# Visual basic datagridview result showing numbers of results not the text

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

Might be a bad title but as a non-english speaking person not everything is simple.

My problem is the following:

1. Fetching data from Mysql database (No problem)
2. Adding a Combobox in my Datagridview (No problem)
3. Inserting the result into that combobox (Problem)

What happens is that the combobox shows me the number of results, it is showing me 212 as a single possibility to click and not the value of the MySQL cell.

My code looks like this:

```
'//Henter drivere fra Printer Installer Database //'
        mysqlconnpi.Open()
        query = "Select model_name from printer_installer.ppp_drivers"
        data = New DataTable
        dataAdap = New Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlDataAdapter(query, mysqlconnpi)
        Dim cmb As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
        cmb.HeaderText = "Select Data"
        cmb.Name = "cmb"
        cmb.MaxDropDownItems = 100
        cmb.Items.Add(dataAdap.Fill(data))
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(cmb)
```

The result is this:

[image]

What is wrong with my code?

Also, I found out that the combobox only could handle 100 items, is there a way for my to get more? I currently have 212 drivers in the database I want to list.

EDIT:

I testet to add this line:
DataGridView1.DataSource = data
to the code just to check if "data" even had items. 
the result is this:
[Not allowed to insert embedded, image is here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwMTM.jpg)

The code is now:

```
            '//Henter drivere fra Printer Installer Database //'
        mysqlconnpi.Open()
        query = "Select model_name from printer_installer.ppp_drivers"
        data = New DataTable
        dataAdap = New Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlDataAdapter(query, mysqlconnpi)
        Dim cmb As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
        cmb.HeaderText = "driver"
        cmb.Name = "cmb"
        cmb.MaxDropDownItems = 100
        cmb.Items.Add(dataAdap.Fill(data))
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(cmb)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = data
        'DataGridView1.DataSource = dataAdap.Fill(data)
        '-------------------------------------------------'
```

Answer (score 0):

The DataGridView might be looking at the string length which is the property of string the result of the query so you might want to send the result by wrapping your string. You can use linq in place of your sql query.

**From model in printer_installer.ppp_drivers select new with {Key .name =model.model_name}**

Comment: So I should make the "query" look like this: query = "Select model_name From model in printer_installer.ppp_drivers select new with {Key .name =model.model_name}" ?       I have not coded for more that a couple of days so correct me if I'm wrong here.

Comment: you check out LINQ or if you want to stick with your code then I think you can make a class with a property to hold your string and make a list of that class from your sql query and pass that list to datagridview